# The click event of LinkButton doesn't call when i add Button to GridView's Cell from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I use below code for add Button to GridView's Cell from code behind `when user click on a button`,but when i click on each button that i add,the click event(lnk_Click) doesn't call and button hides after i click on it.how can i solve this problem?

```
//aspx
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" Width="940px"
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged"
      onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gridview">
       <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="...">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Panel ID="pnlSteps" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>

    //Code behind
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Panel pnl = (Panel)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("pnlSteps");
                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.Text = "...";
                pnl.Controls.Add(lnk);
                lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
            }//for
    ...

    protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    //...
    }
```

I fill the gridview with below code

```
//dsSet is DataSet that i fill it with data from Database
DataTable dtt = new DataTable();

        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("status", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("finantial", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("phone", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("code", typeof(string)));

        for (int i = 0; i < dsSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtt.NewRow();

            dr[0]=...;
            dr[1]=...;
            dr[2]=...;
            dr[3]=...;
            dr[4]=...;

            dtt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }//for
        GridView1.DataSource = dtt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

//Command
i also use `CommandName` like below and set `GridView_RowCommand` to Gridview's `OnRowCommand` but doesn't work

lnk.CommandName = "Select";

protected void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
.....

Comment: Oops I ment to comment.  Are these inside an update panel?  CommandName / GridView_RowCommand is usually the route to go. Giving your link button a CommandName property on creation, and in the GridView_RowCommand check that e.CommandName == "Name you gave link button"

Comment: yes,in update panel,the GridView_RowCommand doesn't call when i click on LinkButtons that i create from code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add controls and events manually you have to add them at each postback. Databind the grid only once **(if(!IsPostBack))** but **execute this loop at each postback**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Panel pnl = (Panel)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("pnlSteps");
            LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Text = "...";
            pnl.Controls.Add(lnk);
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
        }//for
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had simular issues with my link button in the update panel.

I believe I added this trigger to my update panel containing the grid view control.

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
</Triggers>
```

To resolve the issue.  Be sure your gridview is initialized `onRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand"` property set and that your link button has a `CommandName=""` property set.

Then when your link button event fire's you can determine the CommandName that fired it inside the `GridView_RowCommand`.

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.CommandName == "Link Button Command Name")
   {
      // link button
   }
}
```

If this still does not resolve your issue, you may have to try creating the link button in `GridView_RowCreated` or page Pre_Render.

Comment: i set `lnk.CommandName = "Select";` and for Gridview set `OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand"` but this event doesn't call ` protected void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {...`